# JavaScript: Parse Java source code, extract method

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to build a module that returns all methods of a given Java source code using nodeJs. So far I can get the AST tree built using "java-parser" module but I need to traverse it to filter out methods.

```
 code = ' public class CallingMethodsInSameClass
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printOne();
        printOne();
        printTwo();
 }
 public static void printOne() {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
 }

 public static void printTwo() {
    printOne();
    printOne();
} }';

var javaParser = require("java-parser");
var traverse = require("babel-traverse").default;
var methodsList = [];
traverse(ast, {
  enter(path){
  //do extraction
  }
}
```

I understand that babel-traverse is for Js but I wanted a way to traverse so I can filter the methods.
I'm getting this error

```
throw new Error(messages.get("traverseNeedsParent", parent.type));
  ^

 Error: You must pass a scope and parentPath unless traversing a 
 Program/File. Instead of that you tried to traverse a undefined node 
 without passing scope and parentPath.
```

The AST if logged looks like

```
{ node: 'CompilationUnit',
  types: 
   [ { node: 'TypeDeclaration',
       name: [Object],
       superInterfaceTypes: [],
       superclassType: null,
       bodyDeclarations: [Array],
       typeParameters: [],
       interface: false,
       modifiers: [Array] } ],
  package: null,
  imports: [] }
```

where a method will be identified by "MethodDeclaration" within *types*. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AST is just another JSON object. Try `jsonpath`.

```
npm install jsonpath
```

To extract all methods, just filter on condition `node=="MethodDeclaration"`:

```
var jp = require('jsonpath');
var methods = jp.query(ast, '$.types..[?(@.node=="MethodDeclaration")]');
console.log(methods);
```

See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) for more JSON path syntax.